# Efeito pontilhado no select e button no Firefox

Tags: css, front-end, firefox

Existe alguma forma de remover esse pontilhado que aparece quando se clica em um select ou button no firefox?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente isso é a propriedade `outline` do CSS.

Você pode desabilitar assim:

```
select { outline: none }
```

Mais informações sobre essa propriedade: [W3Schools outline Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp).

Comment: Já estou usando outline, mas mesmo assim aparece esse pontilhado.

Comment: Use `select * { outline: none }`, assim, todos os elementos abaixo do `select` não irão ter o `outline`. Caso não resolva, poste seu código completo, com HTML e CSS.

Comment: Isso acontece mesmo sem estilizar, apenas com as tags já acontece.

Comment: Poste seu código fazendo favor, HTML e CSS, para que eu possa te ajudar melhor.